# Load and write text file into html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a html file load and write a .txt file from a webhost or pastebin raw into a textbox or div on the html by using javascript?

Comment: But isn't it for local txt files? And not for online storage text files

Comment: No, the linked question is asking about "online" files. JS in your browser cannot access your local files without user interactions.